# Why do I get an "Out of Memory" exception in this case?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, picturebox

I'm currently working on a school project, so I am new to C#. It consists in a trivia game which can be won if the user answers correctly to all questions from 7 subjects.

The user "spins" the wheel in order to choose one of the 7 subjects. The algorithm below randomizes a number from 1 to 7 and checks if the user has previously answered to the questions from that subject. If not, an image of the wheel spinning until it stops at the chosen subject is given to the "wheel" PictureBox.

The problem I encounter is with this operation. Because it is a multiplayer game, the "wheel spinning" happens more than 14 times and at around 11 spins, the application crashes.

```
var OldImage = wheel.Image;
wheel.Enabled = true; // wheel is a pictureBox
bool ok = true;
while (ok == true)
{
    subject = randomNumber(); // there are 7 possible subjects
    if (done[subject] == 0) // this checks if the user had completed the subject
    {
        wheel.Image = Image.FromFile("Wheel\\Wheel" + subject + ".gif");
        ok = false;
    }
}
await Task.Delay(11500); // the gif stops after 11.5 seconds
wheel.Enabled = false;
if (OldImage != null)
{
    OldImage.Dispose();
}
```

I tried the disposal metthod but it didn't work.

This generates two types of exceptions:

1) `An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code` which points out to `wheel.Image = Image.FromFile("Wheel\\Wheel" + subject + ".gif");`

2) `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` `Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why would you not load all 7 pictures to memory, and just show the picture, rather than constantly try loading them from disk

Comment: Code is insufficien to determine why the error occurs. You need to provide more of your code. Another note: Instead of getting a random number for each spin, create an array with the numbers 1-7 in random order. Doing so will improve your execution in that you don't need to "spin" unnecessarily. Something like `int[] subjects = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray();`

Comment: Should I put this in "randomNumber()"?

Comment: @AndreiDeaconu: You can put that in `randomNumber` but I'd change the method name to something like `getRandomNumbers` and the return value to `int[]` instead of `int`. (Also don't forget to declare `var rnd = new Random();`). You'll also need to keep track of which question it is. I.e. have a counter with the index to `subjects`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me solve the problem!